# WCF for web sites?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I'm working For my company on a .NET N-tier architecture and have several questions. Basics: the project should be split into layers and should not allow tues develop as easy as possible additional modules for modules like logging, ratings, user management etc.

Environment: VS2010, EF4, SQL Server 2008, LinqToSql, c#

Current situation is as follows:
I have a Data Access Layer WHERE I'm using Entity Framework Tues access database ENTITIES.
then I have a Bussines Layer, with all the logic Insert, update, delete and additional methods for searching etc.
The next layer is for WCF Service Contracts
Finally there is a presentation layer (desktop and web).

First I have created a desktop application. After adding a service reference and presentation layer on the left side in the datasources tab all shown all the tables from the database. This is great.

Then I used a datagridview and bound his DataSource to WCF with bindingsource and finally the wizard to order columns etc. This worked fine.

The next try was to make a web site with the functionality itself. Despite the fact that I added a WCF service reference, datasources are not displayed, therefore it is not possible to use the wizard for quick changes and all the stuff must be coded! This work is difficult and needs a lot of code to serve with basic operations like insert, update, delete. But if I add a reference to the Data Access Layer and add in the web.config a connection string, then I can use the wizard. But then, access to datasource (DAL) does not take place through WCF.

I found out that in Asp.net Dynamic Data web site has a basis for insert, update and delete done. It would probably use this a better or I am wrong?

- Question 1: Should the DAL for .edmx use the auto generated code (code generation add items)?
- Question 2: How to to get the same DataSources (in the tab) as in the desktop application?
- Question 3: Is it possible to use WCF in conjunction with Telericks DataGrid as it already supports Ajax by default, insert, update and delete operations?
- Question 4: How to design architecture that will support modularity?

I have spent hours and hours to find concrete informations about this, and still don't know what's the correct and best way. I was searching for articles, where solving of such specific problems would be demonstrated, but didn't found.

I really hope, to get answers/help from you.

Any help is welcome and thanks in advance.

Greetings

Comment: You should split this up into four questions. That will give you a larger chance of them being answered. Also, maybe the MVC framework of Microsoft suits you better as a web framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, as long it gets your work done, otherwise extend.
2. This seems purely design related question; but if you are using telerik, I hope you can find the same for web as well as desktop.
3. Yes. But you will have to tweak the objects returned from web service to set into the telerik datagrid datasource.
4. You've already torn it down to business, data, and ui level; so its *somewhat* modular already. ASP.NET MVC can be your best bet. You can also consider using [ASP.NET Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649096.aspx) to keep the concerns separate logging, authentication.